# How to add a randomly generated number to elements in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to add/subtract a random number from existing elements (floats) in a pandas DataFrame (Python).

`indices` is a random subset index, and `modify_columns` is a list of the columns I wish to modify. My DataFrame is as follows (`active_set.loc[indices,modify_columns]`):

```
    Values
380977  0.0
683042  0.0
234012  0.0
16517   0.0
... ...
```

I would like to add or subtract a randomly generated integer (either -1 or 1) from these values.

I have tried using `(2*np.random.randint(0,2,size=(count))-1)` to generate an array of these random numbers, and add them:

`active_set.loc[indices,modify_columns] = active_set.loc[indices,modify_columns] + (2*np.random.randint(0,2,size=(count))-1)`

This does not work as there is a `ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 1: given 180`. I think I can simply create a second DataFrame with the random numbers, or iterate, but these seem inefficient, and there must be a way to use `.apply`, so I am asking for some help on how to do this.

Comment: can you show what is ur expected output

Comment: `active_set.loc[indices,modify_columns] += np.random.randint( -1, 2, size=len(indices) )`

Comment: @Doyousketch2 - good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***more general***

```
df.loc[indexes,columns] = df.loc[indexes,columns] + 2*np.random.randint(0,50,size=(len(indexes),len(columns)))
```

if you want to add different random values, you can make your `random.randint` the same size as columns

Comment: @jezrael apologies i was writing it :/

Answer (score 0):

Create array by same size like length of indices by parameter `size` for 2d array:

```
arr = 2*np.random.randint(0,2,size=(len(indices), len(modify_columns)))
active_set.loc[indices,modify_columns] += arr
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use `pandas.DataFrame.add` function.

```
vector_to_add = 2*np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(count)) - 1
df.loc[indices, modify_columns] = df.loc[indices, modify_columns].add(vector_to_add, axis='index')
```